# In Wordpress search results, how do I display only a unique instance of each search result?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, duplicates

On my websites, there are PDF files that are duplicates of each other (for a reason). So when I search "File A" I might get:

File A

File A

As a result. They are 2 files with the same name in 2 different posts.

How do I modify my search so that it only display 1 instance of File A, preferably the latest modified one.

Comment: loop thru the each result and check if theres an existing result like it. if there is, do some code, else, do other code. flagged for not having a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a way in which you will write some code, you should take a look on the pre_get_posts hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/ . That way i would probably check if the query `is_search()` and if true i would `array_filter($wp_query->posts)` . If you are looking for a plugin, even though i have not performed similar action, using one, i would suggest [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) or [Wp Extended Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extended-search/)